# Link to specific sheet in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a complicated Google spreadsheet with many sheets and a table of contents. Is there some way to create a link to the sheet names so that with a click one can go directly to the sheet? That is: clicking on the cell "sheet5" switches to sheet5?

Comment: Now there is such an option in Google spreadsheets - you can select Insert -> link and choose Sheets in this spreadsheet. Regretfully, I do not have the reputation needed to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When you switch to a different sheet in Google Spreadsheets, pay attention to the URL in your browser's address bar. At the end of the URL you should see something like:

```
#gid=0
```

This number changes when you switch sheets, and specifies which sheet to display. Copy the entire URL and create a hyperlink to it with this formula:

```
=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsaQpHJE_LShcDJ0dWNudHFZWVJqS1dvb3FLWkVrS0E#gid=0", "LINK TEXT")
```

---

#### With a script

I've thought about this question a lot since I first wrote this answer, and I came up with a solution that involves a script.

With the spreadsheet open, click the **Tools** menu, then **Script editor...**. Paste all this code into the editor:

```
function onOpen(event) {
  var ss = event.source;
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Go to sheet...", functionName: "showGoToSheet"});
  ss.addMenu("Tasks", menuEntries);
}

function showGoToSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.setTitle("Go to sheet...").setWidth(800).setHeight(600);
  var table = app.createFlexTable();
  table.setCellPadding(5).setCellSpacing(0);
  var goToSheetClick = app.createServerHandler('handleGoToSheetClick');
  var widgets = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < allsheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet_name = allsheets[i].getName();
    widgets[i] = app.createHTML(sheet_name).setId(sheet_name).addClickHandler(goToSheetClick);
    table.setWidget(i, 1, widgets[i])
  }
  var panel = app.createSimplePanel();
  panel.add(table);
  app.add(panel);
  ss.show(app);
}

function handleGoToSheetClick(e) {
  var sheet_name = e.parameter.source;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
  sheet.activate();
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Save the script, then refresh the spreadsheet. After a second or two a new menu, **Tasks**, will appear after **Help**. There is one item in this menu: **Go to sheet...**

[image: Tasks > Go to sheet...]

This menu item will open a panel with a list of names of all the sheets in the current spreadsheet. It doesn't look like it, but if you click on one of the sheet names, that sheet will come to the front.

---

As an answer to another question, [this script was improved](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/49227/1344) to include a scrollable view and buttons.

Comment: Yeah I think this is the only viable solution at the moment.  Unfortunately I have not found a way to translate between the name "Sheet5" and the `gid=7`.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. The sheets are numbered in order from the left starting at 0. So if a sheet named "Sheet5" is at `gid=7`, it should be the eighth sheet from the left.

Comment: What I mean is, you cannot find out *programatically* what `gid` Sheet5 is, only manually.  If it's position changes, it's `gid` changes, and you can no longer link to it reliably.

Comment: If you figure out a way to link by name, please post it!

Comment: There is a programmatic way to get the `Id` of a sheet, but, bizarrely, this is not the same as the `gid` in the URL. There is also a programmatic way to activate a sheet, but I'm having a hard time coming up with a suitable trigger for the function.

Comment: I just did a test by creating two additional sheets in one of my docs. I noted the url of the second sheet (gid=1). Then I created a third sheet and noted that (gid=2). I then switched their places, and the gid remained the same, even after reloading the document.

Comment: Let me respond why I've upvoted, but not selected this as an answer (although, as per Alkix's answer it appears that gid is now stable?). I actually had this as my solution for a short while -- but every time I click it (it not only takes two clicks) it opens in a new tab... and soon I'm in a sea of new tabs for the same spreadsheet. *sigh*

Comment: Is there a way to not make it open a new tab?

Comment: @JBWhitmore Consider my lengthy addition to this answer.

Comment: Wow, nice job with the tasks...

Comment: Regarding the script to add the menu item, just hit Alt+shift+K. Gives you a pop-up menu with all the sheet names. Done. (This may be a new feature since you created that script)

Comment: Better Option Available here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18518779/1814867

Comment: Can this be used to simply redirect to a specific URL when a sheet tab is clicked? Since we cannot embed a Google map into a sheet (like an iframe), I need to redirect to my map when the "Map" sheet is clicked.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this from my experience is to tie a function to a button/image. The only drawback is that you cannot pass parameters along with a script assigned to a button. Due to this you will need to make a function specific to each navigation but they can call be a in a single script file.

Steps:

Create an image (Insert -> image) and style it to your preference

Create a custom function with the following:

```
function showSheetByName(Name) {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(Name);
   SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
}
```

and then a function specific to your button

```
function showSheet5() {
   showSheetByName("Sheet5");
}
```

Finally assign this function to your button

```
Assign Script...
showSheet5
```

You should now be able to click on your button and navigate to "Sheet5". This can also be modified to go to a specific area of the sheet as well.

Comment: Instead of adding a function specific to each button, you can hardcode it to the jump to the sheet named in the "current cell", e.g. change the 2nd line to read `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(ss.getActiveCell().getValue());`  - you can then put the "button" on a fixed place on screen and label it "Jump to sheet in current cell" and assign it "showSheetByName" (which now doesn't need a parameter). To use, just highlight the cell with a sheet name (e.g. Sheet5) and click the button. It's a little indirect but works because clicking on a button does not remove the focus from the highlighted cell.

Answer (score 5):

This functionality is now easy to implement without any scripting:

1. Click the cell you'd like to link, and click **`cmd + k`** (or go to `Insert > Insert link`)
2. A popup should now appear at your cell with an option in the `Link` field allowing you to select `Sheets in this spreadsheet`. Click on that, and (as shown in the image below), **you should be able to select from all of the sheets you have already created**. Make sure you have already created the sheet to which you intend to link, otherwise it will not appear as an option.

[image: image showing the 'sheets in this spreadsheet' dropdown]

3. You can enter any text in the `Text` field of the dropdown to be the alias for the link.

Comment: This is today's answer