# "Go to" search in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to have a search feature at the top of my spreadsheet that will actually take me to a row, on the same sheet, based on searching a column for the matching information.  So, I want any user to be able to enter a work order number in a cell and have it search column D (D3:D) for a specific work order # and **actually go to** the row that contains the work order #. I don't want it to return a value, I want to go to the row.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

For the time being at least I think Find is the nearest possible: Select ColumnD, Ctrl+H, enter the `order #`, I guess check Match entire cell contents, and click Find.

There is a thread [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/BgBJrjzuCNI) lamenting the lack of ability to hyperlink to a specific cell and as recently as October 7 "Stillll not implemented..."

There is an answer to [Link to a cell in a Google Spreadsheet via URL?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44473/link-to-a-cell-in-a-google-spreadsheet-via-url/52077#52077) but this does not lead to the edit view (and starts from the premise that the required row is already known).

[Link to specific sheet in Google spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24924/link-to-specific-sheet-in-google-spreadsheet) includes code that might serve as a starting point for a Google Apps script solution.

Comment: Thank you - a bit cumbersome for multiple users but we'll make it work.  Thanks